# Is it possible to record the HDMI output of a laptop to the HDMI input of a desktop?

Tags: linux, video, hdmi, cable, recording

I have a laptop (that only has HDMI output, no input possible) and a desktop (typical one, but the HDMI port can receive input), and I thought if it was possible to somehow record on the desktop, whatever would be transmitted if I connected it to the laptop.

My first thought was FFmpeg but, while I read most of the documentation, and I do feel like recording from `/dev/video*` would be possible, I don't think this particular setup could work without a real device/with just a simple HDMI cable connecting both machine right?

**TL;DR**: I want to record input from HDMI output of laptop to a HDMI input on a desktop computer, with just a basic HDMI cable connecting both.

Beside FFmpeg, I don't have any idea on how to do this.
Here a rough diagram, I made to illustrate the idea.

[image: Diagram.]

Answer (score 1):

If your desktop doesn't already have HDMI capture software, HDMI recorders are a thing (barring DRM, which doesn't seem to be your use-case.). Probably the most affordable ones fall in the "Game Capture Card" category. Searching for that term should produce hits for ~$70US.  If DRM is an issue, it's probably a bit DIY still, but Bunnie Huang's NeTV2 could be a good starting point: https://www.crowdsupply.com/alphamax/netv2

Comment: I would have preferred a software only solution, if possible (ffmpeg come to mind) i just don't know how to capture the hdmi input on the desktop, sent by the laptop.

Comment: Maybe this answer has a helpful pointer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212047/ffmpeg-command-line-for-capturing-and-recording-audio-and-video-in-720p-from-d

Comment: Thanks, but already seen it when i searched if what i wanted could be possible (also it need a decklink card in this case, which is against what i specified), i do appreciate your help though :)

Comment: that page gives you help - figuring out whether ffmpeg can see your video input device: `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy` if it shows up, then proceed down the same page to find the options that device supports.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying.
Didn't thought of using `-list_devices` flag and the `dummy` one, i'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: Nvm what said, the `list_devices` flag is limited to the `dshow` flag, which is windows only (and i'm using linux, forgot to mention it)

Comment: `man ffmpeg` shows that the `-devices` flag lists which devices you have available on your machine.

Comment: Thanks, Dylan I don't know if nordmagnus999 got his HDMI input to work, but for those arriving here by search engine: It does indeed appear that most people use a hardware converter instead (i.e., HDMI to USB3.0, whose output appears as a UVC webcam), along with software (obs-studio, vlc, ffmpeg, etc.) to read the "webcam". For the hardware, I myself chose a DIGITNOW which seems to keep people happy, and has audio input as well (for commentary). They are on Amazon (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B097DBWKFT) but I got one for a few dollars less on eBay. (no affiliation. just my own research)